# Error of first split in cross validation is higher than rest of splits

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to evaluate different regression techniques using 5-fold cross validation, using the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, MultiTaskLasso as Lasso, ElasticNet as Elastic  
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

classifiers = [Ridge, Lasso, Elastic]

kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
splits = kf.split(x_bow)

for classifier in classifiers:
    name = classifier.__name__

    for i, (train_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(splits):
        clf = classifier(alpha=1)

        x_train_split = x_bow[train_idx,:]
        y_train_split = y_np[train_idx,:]
        x_test_split = x_bow[test_idx,:]
        y_test_split = y_np[test_idx,:]

        clf.fit(x_train_split, y_train_split)
        prediction = clf.predict(x_test_split)
        mae = np.mean(np.abs(prediction - y_test_split), axis=1)
        print(f'{name} - split {i+1} - points mae {mae[0]:.2f} price mae {mae[1]:.2f}')
```

This yields the following result:

```
Ridge - split 1 - points mae 3.22 price mae 1.71
Ridge - split 2 - points mae 0.47 price mae 0.41
Ridge - split 3 - points mae 0.23 price mae 0.11
Ridge - split 4 - points mae 0.11 price mae 0.20
Ridge - split 5 - points mae 0.36 price mae 0.67
MultiTaskLasso - split 1 - points mae 4.09 price mae 2.37
MultiTaskLasso - split 2 - points mae 0.26 price mae 0.20
MultiTaskLasso - split 3 - points mae 0.48 price mae 0.36
MultiTaskLasso - split 4 - points mae 0.39 price mae 0.28
MultiTaskLasso - split 5 - points mae 0.45 price mae 0.73
ElasticNet - split 1 - points mae 4.09 price mae 2.37
ElasticNet - split 2 - points mae 0.26 price mae 0.20
ElasticNet - split 3 - points mae 0.48 price mae 0.36
ElasticNet - split 4 - points mae 0.39 price mae 0.28
ElasticNet - split 5 - points mae 0.45 price mae 0.73
```

When looking at the output, I would suspect that the classifier gets a lower error after the first split because it evaluates on a split it already learned on before. However, I do create a new classifier within the for-loop so it should create a new object for the classifier. (So the first split should not affect the others).

My question is: why has the first split a higher error than the others and how can I solve this problem.

Comment: what happens if you shuffle the data before splitting?

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem, apparently the outliers are in the beginning of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data was not shuffled, and the outliers were at the beginning of the dataset.